# Using Spring and JPA to add a row of data to 2 tables at once

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm trying to add a data for a brewery where the data needs to go into 2 tables that are connected with a primary key of ID, I understand how to get it into one table but am struggling to figure out how t insert it into 2 tables at once.

I have tried editing to entity class from the database called breweries.java to be able to insert both the latitude and longitude variables, however, it just adds data to the breweries table.

[[image: Breweries table]

[[image: breweries_geocode]

the code i have for the form is called addBrewery.jsp

```
   </head>
<h3>Enter The Brewery Details!</h3>

<form:form method="POST" action="/Assignment2/breweries/addBrewery" modelAttribute="brewerie">

    <table>
        <tr> 
            <td><form:label path="id">ID</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="id"/></td> 
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="id"/> </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="name"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address1">Address 1</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address1" /></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="address1"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="address2">Address 2</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="address2"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="address2"/> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="city">City</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="city"/> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="state">State</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="state"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="state"/> </td>

        </tr>
           <tr>
            <td><form:label path="code">Code</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="code"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="code"/> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="country">Country</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="country"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="country"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="phone">Phone Number</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="phone"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="phone"/> </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
            <td><form:label path="website">Website</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="website"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="website"/> </td>

        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="image">Image</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="image"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"><form:errors path="image"/> </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="description"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="description"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="addUser">Add User</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="addUser"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="addUser"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="creditLimit">Credit Limit</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="creditLimit"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="creditLimit"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="email"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="latitude">Latitude</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="latitude"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="latitude"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="longitude">Longitude</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="longitude"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="longitude"/> </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

the code for the entity class from the database called Breweries.java, i have edited it to be able to use the latitude and longitude data variable but, still wont add data to both tables and just adds data to he breweries table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries")
@SecondaryTable(name="breweries_geocode")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress1", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address1 = :address1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress2", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address2 = :address2"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCity", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.city = :city"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByState", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.state = :state"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCode", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.code = :code"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCountry", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.country = :country"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByPhone", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByWebsite", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.website = :website"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByImage", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.image = :image"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCreditLimit", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.creditLimit = :creditLimit"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.email = :email")})
public class Breweries implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "address1")
    private String address1;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "address2")
    private String address2;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "add_user")
    private int addUser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "credit_limit")
    private double creditLimit;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
    private float latitude;
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
    private float longitude;

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Breweries() {
    }

    public Breweries(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Breweries(Integer id, String name, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String code, String country, String phone, String website, String image, String description, int addUser, Date lastMod, double creditLimit, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.code = code;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.website = website;
        this.image = image;
        this.description = description;
        this.addUser = addUser;
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getAddUser() {
        return addUser;
    }

    public void setAddUser(int addUser) {
        this.addUser = addUser;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    public double getCreditLimit() {
        return creditLimit;
    }

    public void setCreditLimit(double creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Breweries)) {
            return false;
        }
        Breweries other = (Breweries) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "lit.sd4.model.Breweries[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

the code I have for the service

```
  public void addAnBreweries(Breweries brewerie) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        trans.begin();
        em.persist(brewerie);
        trans.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

the code i have for the BreweriesController.java

```
  @GetMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView displayBreweryAddForm() {
    return new ModelAndView("/addBrewery", "brewerie", new Breweries());
}

@PostMapping("/addBrewery")
public ModelAndView addAnBrewery(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("brewerie") Breweries brewerie, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/addBrewery");
    }
    service.addAnBreweries(brewerie);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/agent");

}
```

this code works for adding a row to one table however I am unsure about how to alter it to add a row to 2 tables

breweries_geocode.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries_geocode")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByBreweryId", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.breweryId = :breweryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLatitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.latitude = :latitude"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLongitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.longitude = :longitude")})
public class BreweriesGeocode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "brewery_id")
    private int breweryId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private float longitude;

    public BreweriesGeocode() {
    }

    public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id, int breweryId, float latitude, float longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBreweryId() {
        return breweryId;
    }

    public void setBreweryId(int breweryId) {
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof BreweriesGeocode)) {
            return false;
        }
        BreweriesGeocode other = (BreweriesGeocode) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "brewery.src.model.BreweriesGeocode[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

DBUtil.java

```
public class DBUtil {
   private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = 
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("taste_PU");

public static EntityManagerFactory getEMF() { return EMF; }
```

}

Comment: I believe you're missing a few pieces in this post. I don't see the definition of the other entity.
The approach to your problem will require 2 sets of entities and services- one for each table. Then in your controller, you will call both the services from your controller mapping, which should make 2 separate transactions.
Before I write a preemptive answer I want to confirm- Is that the approach you are taking?
Or, are you trying to create a foreign key in your table to be able to reference to each other?

Comment: @TheNextProgrammer the foreign key is already created between the two tables as id, when a brewery is deleted in the breweries table, its corresponding latitude and longitude must be deleted in the breweries_geocode table,i did not have the breweries_geo i am not sure which approach is best to take as I am an amateur, i have edited my question to include te breweries_geocode entity and my entity manager class, i how my requirment for the delete will be enough for you to understand which approach i should take. let me know if you need any more information

Comment: How is Breweries and BreweriesGeocode mapped. OnetoOne or one to Many. ie One Breweries can have one or multiple BreweriesGeocode?

Comment: @MyTwoCents there is no mapping between any of the tables in the database

Comment: @TheNextProgrammer actually it's a primary key that's being used, not a foreign key